# Ficheros externos introducidos por usuario

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy con ejercicios de manejo de archivos externos, estoy con un ejercicio de leer un archivo txt creado por mí y escribirlo en otro archivo txt en blanco creado por mí también, estoy en el directorio donde están los dos documentos y sin embargo cuando los llamo me dice que el documento no está en ese directorio, he hecho incluso un código de prueba que me confirma que el archivo existe y está en el mismo lugar donde yo me encuentro, expongo lo que tengo hecho.
Este primer código es de prueba y me confirma lo que ya sé.

```
 import os
 if os.path.exists('ejemplo.txt'):
     fichero = open('ejemplo.txt', 'r')
     print 'El fichero existe'
 else:
     print 'El fichero no exiete'
```

El resultado es este.

```
runfile('D:/Users/sacu/.spyder/tema5.py', wdir='D:/Users/sacu/.spyder')
```

El fichero existe
Y el ejercicio que quiero llevar a cabo es éste.

```
 n_fichero=open(raw_input('Introduzca el nombre del fichero: '),'r')
 n_fichero1=open(raw_input('Introduzca el nombre del fichero: '),'w')
 for linea in n_fichero:
     n_fichero1.write(linea)
 n_fichero.close()
 n_fichero1.close()
```

dando como resultado lo siguiente.

```
n_fichero=open(raw_input('Introduzca el nombre del fichero: '),'r')

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ejemplo'
```

No entiendo lo que ocurre puesto que estoy en el directorio correcto, sé que tiene que ser una tontería, pero no lo pillo, si alguien me echa una mano se lo agradezco. Saludos

Comment: Y no será que tenías que haber contestado `ejemplo.txt` en vez de `ejemplo`?

Comment: Probe el código y funciona OK.